# Method save does not exist when saving Laravel 5.2 model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple form, one of the fields is 'resource'.  I have an Item model which has many Resources.  I'm trying to save both the Item and it's Resource from my form.

Item.php:

```
public function resource()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Resource');
}

public function addResource(Resource $resource)
{
    return $this->resource->save($resource);
}
```

Resource.php:

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item');
}
```

My save method in ItemsController:

```
public function store(CreateItemRequest $request)
{
    //get and save Item
    $item = new Item($request->all());
    Auth::user()->item()->save($item);

    //get and save Resource
    $resource = new Resource(array($request->input('resource')));
    $item->addResource($resource);

    return view('items.index');
}
```

When calling addResource on the Item model, I get this error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method save does not exist.
in Macroable.php line 81
at Collection->__call('save', array(object(Resource))) in Item.php line 41
at Item->addResource(object(Resource)) in ItemsController.php line 73
at ItemsController->store(object(CreateItemRequest))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ItemsController), 'store'), array(object(CreateItemRequest))) in Controller.php line 76
```

I've been stuck on this for way too long!  Any help would be MUCH appreciated.  I'm sure it's a simple newbie mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addResource()` method should look like this:

```
public function addResource(Resource $resource)
{
    $this->resource()->attach($resource->id);
}
```

The *property* `$this->resource` will be resolved to an actual instance of a related model.  If no models have yet been related it will evaluate to `null`.  The *method* `$this->resource()` will actually return the type of relationship that exists between the models (in this case, it should return `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany`).

Comment: Thank you so much, it works much better using the $this->resource() method!