# Laravel Error : Method save does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I've been create a code for updating data to database, but I'm get error like below. when I debugging the code using `dd()`, the value was true.
what's wrong with my `save()` method ?

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
>     Method save does not exist.

this my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

 /*
 <---- this line is my another code ---->
 */

   $input = Input::all();
    $servicedata = $input['service_id'];
    $employeedata = $input['emp_id'];

    foreach ($servicedata as $key => $val) {
        $detailservice = DetailServiceOrder::find($request->detail_service_id);
        $detailservice->sales_order_id = $request->sales_order_id;
        $detailservice->service_id = $input['service_id'][$key];
        $detailservice->order_type = $input['order_type'][$key];
        $detailservice->select_plan = $input['select_plan'][$key];
        $detailservice->qty = $input['qty'][$key];
        $detailservice->unit_price = $input['unit_price'][$key];
        $detailservice->note = $input['note'][$key];
        $detailservice->save();
    }

    foreach ($employeedata as $key => $val) {
        $detailemployee = DetailEmployeeOrder::find($request->detail_employee_id);
        $detailemployee->sales_order_id = $request->sales_order_id;
        $detailemployee->employee_id = $input['emp_id'][$key];
        $detailemployee->mandays = $input['mandays'][$key];
        $detailemployee->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that `DetailServiceOrder::find` doesn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

You should always check if query returns null. Use [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) or [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
foreach ($servicedata as $key => $val) {
    $detailservice = DetailServiceOrder::find($request->detail_service_id);
    if (!is_null($detailservice)) {
        $detailservice->sales_order_id = $request->sales_order_id;
        $detailservice->service_id = $input['service_id'][$key];
        $detailservice->order_type = $input['order_type'][$key];
        $detailservice->select_plan = $input['select_plan'][$key];
        $detailservice->qty = $input['qty'][$key];
        $detailservice->unit_price = $input['unit_price'][$key];
        $detailservice->note = $input['note'][$key];
        $detailservice->save();
    }
}

foreach ($employeedata as $key => $val) {
    $detailemployee = DetailEmployeeOrder::find($request->detail_employee_id);
    if (!is_null($detailemployee)) {
        $detailemployee->sales_order_id = $request->sales_order_id;
        $detailemployee->employee_id = $input['emp_id'][$key];
        $detailemployee->mandays = $input['mandays'][$key];
        $detailemployee->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, i've been following your way but it's still error

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try different approach?

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

 /*
 <---- this line is my another code ---->
 */

   $input = Input::all();
    $servicedata = $input['service_id'];
    $employeedata = $input['emp_id'];

    foreach ($servicedata as $key => $val) {
        DetailServiceOrder::where('detail_service_id', $request->detail_service_id)->
            update(['sales_order_id' = $request->sales_order_id, 
                    'service_id' = $input['service_id'][$key], 
                    'sales_order_id' = $request->sales_order_id, 
                    'order_type' = $input['order_type'][$key], 
                    'select_plan' = $input['select_plan'][$key], 
                    'qty' = $input['qty'][$key], 
                    'unit_price' = $input['unit_price'][$key], 
                    'note' = $input['note'][$key] ]);            
    }

    foreach ($employeedata as $key => $val) {
        DetailEmployeeOrder::where('detail_employee_id', $request->detail_employee_id)->
            update(['sales_order_id' = $request->sales_order_id,                         
                    'employee_id' = $input['emp_id'][$key], 
                    'mandays' = $input['mandays'][$key] ]);                 
    }
}
```

In this case you don't need to check if record exists because it doesn't use `save()` method.

For more help check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#updates).

Hope it helps

Comment: it's working, but the problem now is the saved data only the last data, foreach seems not working

Comment: It should work. `Foreach` seems good, so i don't get it where is problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

`$detailservice` is null i think, you should check if it null or not

```
if ( ! $detailservice) continue;
```

Comment: but when i check using `dd($detailservice)` the value is not null

Comment: see this link here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896756/method-save-does-not-exist-when-saving-laravel-5-2-model

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, in my case is was just because i use ->get() instead of ->first() like a dummy, obviously there is no method save on a collection... So i reply if someone see this question like me in my research